# Possible to modify clip dimensions once clipped, in InkScape?

Tags: inkscape

Within InkScape, is it possible to modify the clip dimensions once the object is clipped?  I would like to include more area of what I am visually displaying, within the clipped state. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to node-editing mode with the clipped object selected, enable the 'Show clipping path(s) of selected object(s)' setting in the toolbar and manipulate the clip-path directly.

[image: 'Show clipping path(s) of selected object(s)' setting highlighted in the toolbar]

Alternatively, since clipping is non-destructive, you can just right-click the clipped object, select 'Release Clip', modify the clipping object, then re-clip.